# Kill thread with opened socket in Tomcat

Tags: multithreading, sockets, jakarta-ee, tomcat

In my application running under Tomcat 7.x, a servlet starts a new Thread. In this thread, I create a socket (on port 8081) which waits until a client connects (`serverSocket.accept()`).

When undeploying the app, the thread is not killed. That's why when I redeploy the app, my new socket can't listen on port 8081 as the former socket is still listenning on it. I also obtain a 'memory leak' in the console logs.

I tried to `setDaemon(true)` on my thread but it doesn't solve the problem. How should I do?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the socket in the destroy() method. The thread blocked in accept() will throw an IOException: let it exit from there.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. But what if a client is connected and sending a large amount of data via a POST request? Will the sub-thread dedicated to this client be killed as well?

Comment: No. It should exit when it reads EOS from the connection, and/or closes it itself. Closing the listening socket has no effect on accepted sockets.

Comment: Thanks. So I should then manually close all accepted sockets?

Comment: It depends on your requirement. If their service times are short it may be more convenient just to let them finish what they're doing, or perhaps if they're still reading the request they could abort themselves and close the socket. If service times are long you should close them manually to let Tomcat stop the application.